# Write and read from URL in jQuery element filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, filter

I have got jQuery function (thanks to @CarstenLøvboAndersen again) for filtering elements.
For example: If I check RED and BLUE then it filter only elements with both class RED and BLUE. When I click all, script uncheck all checkboxes and show all elements.

I need to improve the function with the possibility of saving parameters in the URL and reading them again.

Simply said: I need link page with filter's parameters

Any idea how to do it... Thank you in advance

```js
$('.selector button').click(function() {
  $('.selector input').prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
  var classes = "";
  $(".filterelements div").hide();
  $(".selector input:checked").each(function() {
    classes += "." + $(this).val();
  });
  $(".filterelements div"+classes).show();
})
```

```css
.filterelements {
  width: 210px;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue,
.redgreen,
.redblue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff2600;
}

.green {
  background: #a5de00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0087ff;
}

.redgreen {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.redblue {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="selector">
      <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
      <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
      <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">blue
      <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green
    </div>



    <hr />
    <div class="filterelements">
      <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
      <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
      <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
      <div class="redgreen red green" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
      <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
      <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
      <div class="redblue red blue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had something like this in mind?
(the code could be further optimized of course, it's purely an example ;) )

```js
function filterColors() {
let classes = "";

$(".filterelements div, #no-results").hide();

$(".selector input:checked").each(function() {
    classes += "." + $(this).val();
});

$(".filterelements div"+classes).show();

if (!$(".filterelements div").is(':visible')) {
    $("#no-results").show();
}
}

function getColorsParams() {
    let url_string = window.location.href,
        url        = new URL(url_string),
        colors     = url.searchParams.get("c");
        
    if (colors !== null) {
        colors.split("+").forEach(function(param) {
            $('.selector input[value="' + param + '"]').prop("checked", true);
        });
    
        filterColors();
    }
}


function setColorsParams() {
   let params = "";
  
   $(".selector input:checked").each(function(i, selected) {
      if (i > 0) {
        params = params + "+";
      }  
   
      params = params + $(selected).val(); 
   });
     
   let url_string = window.location.href,
       newUrl     = new URL(url_string);
      
       if (params === "") {
           newUrl.searchParams.delete("c");
       } else {
           newUrl.searchParams.set("c", params); 
       }
  
       window.history.pushState({}, '', newUrl);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getColorsParams();
});

$('.selector button').click(function() {
    $('.selector input').prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
    filterColors();
    setColorsParams();
});
```

```css
            .filterelements {
  width: 210px;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue,
.redgreen,
.redblue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff2600;
}

.green {
  background: #a5de00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0087ff;
}

.redgreen {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
}
    #no-results {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="selector">
        <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
        <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">blue
        <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green
      </div>
  
  
  
      <hr />
      <div class="filterelements">
        <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
        <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
        <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
        <div class="redgreen red green" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
        <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
        <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
        <div class="redblue red blue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="no-results">No results</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @arvie for help. I tested your solution and I have got two questions:
1. I see URL in console but it is not changed in adress bar, so I tride to add someting like window.location.replace (newUrl), but it reload page. How to do it without reloading, for example is it possible to do it with # (hash) something like # filter-red / green / blue instead of ?c=
2. When I open page without any parameter I get error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
Thanks in advance

Comment: @TomášSiničák Ok clear, I've changed the code in my answer. To prevent a window reload we can use HTML5's  history.pushState .
I think you could use a # , but a hash is rather used to move the page to corresponding id attribute of an element :)

Comment: oh thanks @arvie for upgrade script, now it works well done ( +1 ). I have got last question, is it possible to add some text, when is there combination without result? Ex. check GREEN and BLUE. There is no result, co script will write "NO RESULT".

Comment: @TomášSiničák it's possible to check if an element is visible in jQuery   $("my-element").is(':visible')  . I've updated the code.